# Why is this a Checkmate? Pawn can capture queen?

Tags: checkmate, beginner, check

[image: board]

I am just learning Chess. Why is this a checkmate? It's Black's turn, and White's queen threatens Black's king, so check. But if I play gxf8, the check is gone. Why doesn't the game let me do it?

Comment: Well, it must be that black starts from the top. In that case, pawns cannot move backward so `gxf8` is not possible. You can check this by seeing the coordinates of the board on the side.

Comment: Protip: If you are a total rookie, always play with a board that has numbered/lettered ranks and files, so that you can immediately see in which direction the pawns move. Online resources can be lazy in that regard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the usual orientation of pictures, black starts at the top and moves *down*, so the pawn would have to capture *backward* to take the queen. The actual pattern you see is a prime example of a "back rank/row mate".